# Unable to adjust weight paints

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

So I'm working on a character I want to animate, and the eyes and hair are being manipulated by my arm bones. I have gone into weight paint mode and tried to erase the weights on the eyes. This did not seem to fix it. I tried again in wireframe mode to make sure I didn't miss any of the geography, and that still didn't work. Is there a way to see which vertex groups are affecting the area in question?

Here is the character both before and after posing:

[image]

[image]

its more noticeable with the hair, but its essentially the same issue.

Comment: Leave the bone in pose mode, then select the Object that should not be modified, and hit control tab. It should turn into a collection of colors anywhere from blue to green to yellow to orange to red, which each part of that range band indicating a different percentage of influence, with blue being 0% and red being 100%. With the mesh you want to remove influence from selected, click on each child bone on the extremity that is influencing the wrong bodypart. Once you start seeing colors other than blue you found the right bone.

Comment: maybe this answer will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145042/leftover-vertices-after-parenting-to-bone-mouth-eyeballs-not-rigged/145065#145065